# CSS Tooltip Issue - Span hidden behind Facebook like box and Main Body

Tags: css, z-index, tooltip

I am using pure CSS based tooltip, but having display issue. The span box is hiding behind main boday and facebook like box which is in right sidebar. Below is the screenshot of the same.

[image: Tooltip]

**Here is the tooltip CSS.**

```
a.tooltip
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.tooltip span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-left: -160px;
    text-align: justify;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: 40px; /** Use 30px for simple fade in effect - Removes slide down effect **/

    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/** CSS Down Arrow **/      
a.tooltip span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

a:hover.tooltip span {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
}

a.imgleft {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
}

a.imgright {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
}

a.imgleft span, a.imgright span {
    bottom: 140px;
}

a:hover.imgleft span, a:hover.imgright span {
    bottom: 130px;
}


/** Span Color **/
a.ttblue {
    color: #E45742;
}

a.ttblue span {
    background: #E45742;
    border: 4px solid #E45742;
    color: #FFF;
}

a.ttblue span:after {
    border-top: 10px solid #E45742;
}
```

**any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I believe we had to see more of your pages html to be able to help you.

However, the only problem I can imagine is `.tooltip` being in a different stacking context than right sidebar's.

Does any of `.tooltip's` parents/grandparents have a `z-index` or an `opacity` level set on it? It might be an opacity level. If it is, set a positive z-index on it (or if sidebar has a `z-index` too, a higher one than `sidebar`'s).

Comment: Hi @JOPLOmacedo, I am using z-index only in main menu which is z-index: 400; and z-index:200; not even for right sidebar. Not using opacity as well.

`#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
}`

`.menu-header_menu-container ul ul {position: absolute; width:128px; display:none; z-index: 400;}`